# Fedora24 - Puppet not applying config but returns without error

Tags: puppet

I'm new to Puppet. Just did a fresh install but not able to get config applied to agent from master. Installed master using "dnf -y install puppet-server.noarch" Installed agent using "dnf -y install puppet.noarch"

puppet.conf from master

```
cat /etc/puppet/puppet.conf 
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath =  /var/lib/puppet/facts.d:/var/lib/puppet/lib/facter:/var/lib/puppet/facts
certname = master.puppettest.com
server = master.puppettest.com
[master]
dns_alt_names = master,master.puppettest.com
```

puppet.conf from agent

```
cat /etc/puppet/puppet.conf 
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath =  /var/lib/puppet/facts.d:/var/lib/puppet/lib/facter:/var/lib/puppet/facts
[agent]
server = master.puppettest.com
```

Debug output from agent

```
puppet agent -t -d
Debug: Applying settings catalog for sections main, agent, ssl
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'confdir': 'File[/etc/puppet]{:path=>"/etc/puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dsimport does not exist
Debug: Failed to load library 'ldap' for feature 'ldap'
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: feature ldap is missing
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file roleadd does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
Debug: Failed to load library 'ldap' for feature 'ldap'
Debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderLdap: feature ldap is missing
Debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'vardir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'logdir': 'File[/var/log/puppet]{:path=>"/var/log/puppet", :mode=>"750", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statedir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state", :mode=>"1755", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'rundir': 'File[/var/run/puppet]{:path=>"/var/run/puppet", :mode=>"755", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'libdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/lib", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'preview_outputdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/preview]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/preview", :mode=>"750", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'certdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs", :mode=>"755", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'ssldir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl", :mode=>"771", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'publickeydir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys", :mode=>"755", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'requestdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests", :mode=>"755", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatekeydir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys", :mode=>"750", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatedir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private", :mode=>"750", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostcert': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/agent.puppettest.com.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/agent.puppettest.com.pem", :mode=>"644", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostprivkey': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/agent.puppettest.com.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/agent.puppettest.com.pem", :mode=>"640", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostpubkey': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/agent.puppettest.com.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/agent.puppettest.com.pem", :mode=>"644", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'localcacert': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem", :mode=>"644", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostcrl': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/crl.pem", :mode=>"644", :owner=>"puppet", :group=>"puppet", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statefile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml", :mode=>"660", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'clientyamldir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'client_datadir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/client_data]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/client_data", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'classfile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/classes.txt]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/classes.txt", :mode=>"640", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'resourcefile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/resources.txt]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/resources.txt", :mode=>"640", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'clientbucketdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'lastrunfile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml", :mode=>"644", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'lastrunreport': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml", :mode=>"640", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'graphdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'pluginfactdest': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/facts.d", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/preview]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/agent.puppettest.com.pem]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/agent.puppettest.com.pem]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/agent.puppettest.com.pem]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_data]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/classes.txt]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/resources.txt]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: Finishing transaction 47333324902120
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Runtime environment: puppet_version=4.2.1, ruby_version=2.3.1, run_mode=agent, default_encoding=UTF-8
Debug: Using cached certificate for ca
Debug: Using cached certificate for agent.puppettest.com
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Loaded state in 0.01 seconds
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: node supports formats: pson yaml binary
Debug: Using cached certificate for ca
Debug: Using cached certificate for agent.puppettest.com
Debug: Creating new connection for https://master.puppettest.com:8140
Debug: Using cached certificate_revocation_list for ca
Debug: Starting connection for https://master.puppettest.com:8140
Debug: Caching connection for https://master.puppettest.com:8140
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: file_metadata supports formats: pson yaml binary
Debug: Using cached connection for https://master.puppettest.com:8140
Debug: Caching connection for https://master.puppettest.com:8140
Debug: Finishing transaction 47333324555320
Info: Retrieving plugin
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: file_metadata supports formats: pson yaml binary
Debug: Using cached connection for https://master.puppettest.com:8140
Debug: Caching connection for https://master.puppettest.com:8140
Debug: Finishing transaction 47333318004940
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Loading external facts from /var/lib/puppet/facts.d
Info: Loading facts
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for ec2_metadata
Debug: Facter: value for ec2_metadata is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for agent_specified_environment is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for cfkey is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for vlans is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for xendomains
Debug: Facter: value for xendomains is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for ec2_metadata
Debug: Facter: value for ec2_metadata is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for ec2_userdata
Debug: Facter: value for ec2_userdata is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for zfs_version is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for zonename
Debug: Facter: value for zonename is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for gce
Debug: Facter: value for gce is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for zpool_version is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6_ens2 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6_lo is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for macaddress_lo is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6 is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 2 for iphostnumber
Debug: Facter: value for iphostnumber is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for lsbdistcodename
Debug: Facter: value for lsbdistcodename is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for lsbdistdescription
Debug: Facter: value for lsbdistdescription is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for lsbdistid
Debug: Facter: value for lsbdistid is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for lsbdistrelease
Debug: Facter: value for lsbdistrelease is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for is_rsc is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for is_rsc is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for rsc_region
Debug: Facter: value for rsc_region is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for is_rsc is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for rsc_instance_id
Debug: Facter: value for rsc_instance_id is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for lsbmajdistrelease
Debug: Facter: value for lsbmajdistrelease is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for lsbminordistrelease
Debug: Facter: value for lsbminordistrelease is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for lsbrelease
Debug: Facter: value for lsbrelease is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 2 for swapencrypted
Debug: Facter: value for swapencrypted is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for processor
Debug: Facter: value for processor is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for selinux_enforced
Debug: Facter: value for selinux_enforced is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for selinux_policyversion
Debug: Facter: value for selinux_policyversion is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for selinux_current_mode
Debug: Facter: value for selinux_current_mode is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for selinux_config_mode
Debug: Facter: value for selinux_config_mode is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for selinux_config_policy
Debug: Facter: value for selinux_config_policy is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshdsakey is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshdsakey is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshfp_dsa is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for system32
Debug: Facter: value for system32 is still nil
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: catalog supports formats: pson yaml dot binary
Debug: Using cached connection for https://master.puppettest.com:8140
Debug: Caching connection for https://master.puppettest.com:8140
Info: Caching catalog for agent.puppettest.com
Debug: Creating default schedules
Debug: Loaded state in 0.00 seconds
Info: Applying configuration version '1468533074'
Debug: Finishing transaction 47333324429420
Debug: Storing state
Debug: Stored state in 0.01 seconds
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.04 seconds
Debug: Using cached connection for https://master.puppettest.com:8140
Debug: Caching connection for https://master.puppettest.com:8140
Debug: Closing connection for https://master.puppettest.com:8140
```

Something is wrong loading facts I think. I see the folder facts.d is empty on both master and agent. Did I miss anything?

```
[root@agent catalog]#  ls /var/lib/puppet/facts.d/
[root@agent catalog]#
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: `/var/lib/puppet/facts.d/` is where external facts are placed on client servers. It has no relevance here.

Comment: Thank You. So this is not the issue. Is there anything else I can take a look? I don't see any log file being generated in /var/log/puppet folder, which is strange.

Comment: It looks entirely ordinary to me, just a successful run with no content. Puppet agents normally log to syslog (probably journal under Fedora) as puppet-agent.  If you've added manifests, modules etc that aren't running, please edit and add details to the question.

Comment: As @m0dlx suggests, there's a big difference between "not applying config" and applying an empty config.  The latter appears to be what you're experiencing.  If that's the case then the problem is in your manifests -- perhaps lack of a site manifest.

Comment: Issue get resolved after moving configuration file to production folder. It's in the default environment.